# How do I make the whole area of a list item in my navigation bar, clickable as a link?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I've got a horizontal navigation bar made from an unordered list, and each list item has a lot of padding to make it look nice, but the only area that works as a link is the text itself.  How can I enable the user to click anywhere in the list item to active the link?

```css
#nav {
  background-color: #181818;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#nav img {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #181818;
  float: left;
}

#nav li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 25px 10px;
}

#nav li:hover {
  background-color: #785442;
}

#nav a {
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <img src="/images/renderedicon.png" alt="Icon" height="57" width="57" />
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Heading</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Don't put padding in the 'li' item. Instead set the anchor tag to `display:inline-block;` and apply padding to it.

Comment: `display: inline; zoom: 1;` in a conditional comment for IE6 and IE7 will replace `display: inline-block;` though yes, if list items are already floated, `display: block;` will be OK too

Comment: That worked nicely only one complaint, it didn't seem to work with the :after selector. I wanted a `>` symbol to appear after my link text, but not put it in the content... I ended up just putting it in the content. Would be curious if there's a better way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 48):

Define your anchor tag css property as:

```
{display:block}
```

Then the anchor will occupy the entire list area, so your click will work in the empty space next to your list.

Comment: I wish, I could drag this answer on top of the answer list... This is the best solution for this problem!!!!

Comment: Will break lines if anything else is in the `li`, such as an icon.

Answer (score 13):

Make the anchor tag contain the padding rather than the `li`. This way, it will take up all the area.

Comment: I would also suggest moving the hover state to the anchor as well off of the li for better browser support.

Answer (score 13):

Super, super late to this party, but anyway: you can also style the anchor as a flex item. This is particularly useful for dynamically sized/arranged list items.

```
a {
  /* This flexbox code stretches the link's clickable 
   * area to fit its parent block. */
  display:        flex;
  flex-grow:      1;
  flex-shrink:    1;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

(Caveat: flexboxes are obvs still not well supported. Autoprefixer to the rescue!)

Comment: But now (a few years later), flex is working well so I think it is the best answer when building the menu with `ul` and flexbox.

Comment: I think this answer should be at the top, now that flexbox is implemented in all browsers

Answer (score 11):

Use following:

```css
a {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Or you could use jQuery:

```
$("li").click(function(){
   window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
   return false;
});
```

Comment: One can say that this solution is 'dirty jquery solution which is not needed because you can do it easily with css'. But to be honest - sometimes you find yourself in situation working with not-your-code and you simply don't have a time to get to know all DOM structure and css stylesheets (and trying to understand 'what coder was thinking'). So +1.

Comment: Agree with @lemoid, we have to remember "pretty" solutions are not always practical in Real Life.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this CSS property and value into your `li`:

```
pointer-events:all;
```

So, you can handle the link with jQuery or JavaScript, or use an `a` tag, but all other tag elements inside the `li` should have the CSS property:

```
pointer-events:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply apply the below css :

```
<style>
  #nav ul li {
    display: inline;
  }

  #nav ul li a {
    background: #fff;// custom background
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how I did it

Make the `<a>` inline-block and remove the padding from your `<li>`

Then you can play with the `width` and the `height` of the `<a>` in the `<li>`

Put the `width` to `100%` as a start and see how it works

PS:- Get the help of Chrome Developer Tools when changing the `height` and `width`

Answer (score 0):

If you have some constraint where you need to keep `<li>` structure as is and would like your a tag to take up the full area within the li element you can do the following:

```
a {
    display: flex !important;
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Put the list item within the hyperlink instead of the other way round.

For example with your code:

```
<a href="#"><li>One</li></a>
```

Comment: @DannyBeckett It's valid in HTML5.

Comment: @Tek [No it isn't](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&useragent=Validator.nu%2FLV+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices&doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%3Bbase64%2CPCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw%2BPGh0bWw%2BCjxoZWFkPjx0aXRsZT5UZXN0PC90aXRsZT48L2hlYWQ%2BCjxib2R5Pgo8YSBocmVmPSIjIj48bGk%2BT25lPC9saT48L2E%2BCjwvYm9keT4KPC9odG1sPg%3D%3D).

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of block elements allowed inside anchors but I didn't know ul children were one of the exceptions to the rule. http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/introduction.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values

Thanks for the speedy correction.

Comment: Oh no no no... your syntax and semantic markup just went out the window. Never do this again my friend, it just makes the web a horrible place.