# CSS make div selectable instead of text?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I have a navigation dropdown element that I would like to make selectable - currently the link only works when the text is hovered and not the box surrounding it. Is there a way in which I can do this in CSS.

My CSS code:

```
.main-menu {
position: absolute;
top:90px;
right:0px;
text-align: right;
 z-index: 2000;
}

.main-menu ul {
width: 50%;
background-color: #333;
 display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 20px 5px;
list-style: none;
color: #fff;
}
.main-menu ul li {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -10px;
position: relative;
padding: 17px 15px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 700;
 }
.main-menu ul li a {
color: #fff;
border: none;
}
.main-menu ul li a:hover {
color: #f1c40f;
}
/* sub menu */
.main-menu ul li ul {
position: absolute;
top: 25px;
left: 0;
min-width: 150px;
opacity: 0;
margin: 10px 0px;
padding: 17px 5px 0px 5px;
visibility: hidden;
text-align: left;
}
.main-menu ul li ul li {
display: block;
color: #fff;
margin: 0px -5px;
}
.main-menu ul li ul li:hover {
background: #666;
color: #f1c40f;
}

.main-menu ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

Jsfiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/9BdTK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1

You can simply move the `<a></a>` outside of `<li>`.

**E.G:**

```
<a href="#nowhere" title="Home"><li>Home</li></a>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/9BdTK/1/)

*Note: I have only done this for the first two links.*

---

## Method 2

A better way to do this is the following:

### HTML:

```
<div id="con">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#test1">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#test2">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#test3">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#con {
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    outline: 1px solid #000;
}

a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Keep `<a>` inside and set it to `display: block;`, then set the `width` and `height` to `100%` and this will take up the whole `div` creating a div link.

Demo of div link - [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/feLFn/)

Demo with hover - [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/feLFn/1/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Method 2 is better as it is illegal markup to put anything other than `<li>` inside a `<ul>`

Comment: @SLC Agreed, I did put "_A better way to do this is the following:_" to let them know its the better way.

Answer (score 1):

I have this on my site, but I also managed to do so from this site.

have a look :

> Don't put padding in the 'li' item. Instead set the anchor tag to
>   display:inline-block; and apply padding to it.By Stussa

As said on : [Make whole area clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074454/how-do-i-make-the-whole-area-of-a-list-item-in-my-navigation-bar-clickable-as-a)

Goodluck