# Clickable <a> tag background

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, href

I've made a nav menu with this code:

```
    <nav id="navitems">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="page1.html" id="link">PAGE 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">PAGE 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

I used CSS to make the links look like buttons and sit next to each other. However, I can only click the text to activate the link, not the background (button).

My question is: how can I make the grey area around the link also lead to the same link?

Comment: Please provide your current CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make the whole area of a list item in my navigation bar, clickable as a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074454/how-do-i-make-the-whole-area-of-a-list-item-in-my-navigation-bar-clickable-as-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to emmanuel's answer is to add some padding to the `a` tag:

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
li { 
    float:left;
}
a {
    background:grey;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin-right:1px;
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/rufneu0w/1/

Answer (score 3):

`<a>` elements by default `display`ed as `inline`. You should change it to `block` to occupy the entire space of its parent.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
}
li a {
  background: orange;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navitems">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="link">PAGE 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">PAGE 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You could use `href="#"` to avoid broken page loads