# Make whole list clickable with having a tag inside, while using grid for the entire container

Tags: html, css

I am using grid for ul tag, but also want to make whole li clickable.

How is it possible?

```html
<ul>
  <li class="wedding-bouqette">
    <a href="#">
      <h3 class="bouqette-title">Свадебные букеты</h3>
      <span class="bouqette-desc">Букеты для невест</span>
    </a>
  </li>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make the whole area of a list item in my navigation bar, clickable as a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074454/how-do-i-make-the-whole-area-of-a-list-item-in-my-navigation-bar-clickable-as-a)

Comment: Create class `.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}`   and apply to li as `<li class="wedding-bouqette pointer ">`

Comment: @NavnathJadhav if they don't see to it that the whole area of the LI is actually _made_ "clickable", then that cursor would just be confusing for the user, because it shows the pointer symbol in places that do _not_ react to clicks.

Comment: Even though you can wrap it around block elements in HTML5 now, `a` is still an inline element from the CSS perspective. Apply `display: block` to it, and you should see the behavior change.